# Next page url in amazon web scraping takes to amazon login page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, pagination

I am using requests and beautifulSoup to make a Amazon web scraper which gets all the reviews of a given product. The reviews of the first page are scraped as intended, but, when the code is given the url of subsequent pages, amazon returns the sign in url and the code fails.

```
def getnextpage(soup):
    amazonUrl = amazon.in/
    page = soup.find('ul', class_='a-pagination')
    if not page.find('li', class_='a-disabled a-last'):
        url = amazonUrl + str(page.find('li', class_='a-last').find('a')['href'])
        return url
    else:
        return False
```

This is the function that gets the url of the next page from the amazon product reviews page.

[Amazon Product Review Next Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t9yt.png)

The code should return

https://www.amazon.in/Sony-WH-1000XM5-Wireless-Cancelling-Headphones/product-reviews/B09XS7JWHH/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_paging_btm_2?ie=UTF8&pageNumber=2&reviewerType=all_reviews

But rather it return

https://www.amazon.in/https://www.amazon.in/ap/signin?openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.in%2FSony-WH-1000XM5-Wireless-Cancelling-Headphones%2Fproduct-reviews%2FB09XS7JWHH%3Fie%3DUTF8%26pageNumber%3D2&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=inflex&openid.mode=checkid_setup&marketPlaceId=A21TJRUUN4KGV&language=en&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0

Comment: Maybe, you're getting detected? Why don't you just parse the next page yourself then?

Comment: Well just tried that, 
url = baseReviewUrl + f'?pageNumber={count}'
Used a loop to increament the count and got https://www.amazon.in/Sony-WH-1000XM5-Wireless-Cancelling-Headphones/product-reviews/B09XS7JWHH/?pageNumber=2

This time url is right. But still the html page I get from this url is amazon login page :(

Comment: Well then your're most likely getting detected. You might try using [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) or undetected-chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

scrapy or beautifulsoup will not be able to scrape amazon anymore, use selenium create browser object and request the page driver.get('url') extract all the data from here and get the object of all reviews by locating element  all_reviews = driver.find_element(By.CSSS_ELECTOR,'#reviews-medley-footer .a-text-bold') and click on it with all_reviews.click().
Get the next page object
nextpage = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '')
Scrape all the reviews along with informations you need and
nextpage.click()
do it in a while loop untill nextpage.

It is slow but works smoothly.
https://github.com/ShivNandan-28/Amazon-Selenium-Scraper